# can't get images to load in chrome using js/jquery

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I've made a script to load in a numerical sequence of images from a dir into a grid on an html page.

Im using js/jquery to do this, and it works perfectly well in firefox and safari, but will not load images in chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<HTML>

<head>


<style>
body{
    margin:0;
}
div.gL{
    padding:8px;
    width:1008px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:white;
    height:1%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div.gL ul li{
    width:320px;
    height:230px;
    margin:8px;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
}


.info{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:320px;
    height:230px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    display:none;
}

.list{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    list-style-position:inherit;
}
.game{
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    }

div.info h2{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:32%;
}

img{
    text-align: center;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    top:0;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="gL">
    <ul class="list">
    </ul>    
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function(){
            $.fn.rollbounce = function(){
                $(this).animate({'top': '-=15px'},150).animate({'top': '+=15px'},100).animate({'top': '-=5px'},100).animate({'top': '+=5px'},100)
            }

            var 
                $list = $('ul.list'),
                $info = $('div.info'),
                $li = '<li class="game"></li>'

            for(var p=0; p <= 68; p++){
                if(p<10){
                    p = '00'+p;
                } else if(p<100){
                    p ='0'+p;
                }


                $list.append($.parseHTML($li))
                console.log('this is number'+p)
                $('.game:nth-child('+p+')').append("<img src=img/image_"+p+".jpg/>").prepend("<div class='info'><h2>This is game #"+p+"</h2></div>")

            };


            $game = $('.game')

            $game.on('mouseenter',function(){
                $(this).rollbounce()
                $(this).children('.info').fadeToggle(200)
            }).on('mouseleave',function(){
                $(this).children('.info').fadeToggle(200)
            })
        });
</script>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Obviously, it wont work in fiddle itself since it has no images to pool from but im hoping someone will be able to tell right off why it might not work, or do a quick test on their own and find it out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you checked the console in the developer tools? Errors?

Comment: he will just get some 404

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes :

```
$('.game:nth-child('+p+')')
    .append("<img src='img/image_"+p+".jpg'/>")
    .prepend("<div class='info'><h2>This is game #"+p+"</h2></div>")
```

your `/>` at the end is messing up the url.

**Working Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/PE2gm/4/

**Not working fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/PE2gm/3